# Cross referencing structure from single data input

Tags: c#, .net

Another one of my can't see the wood for the trees questions.

**Background**

I've got a requirement to query a predefined structure for cooking equivalents across (at the moment) a small range of cultures. The structure won't change but the possibility of other cultures and/or equivalents being introduced is a very strong possibility.

**Problem**

I would like to put in place a 2nd 'structure' that would allow me to retain the core of what I've been given, but at the same time, allow me to intelligently input the equivalent measurements only once. In the example below, I've only created an equivalent for a UK measurement to return it's partner Metric and US counterparts. My aim would be that from this single input, the structure would be able to spit back a UK equivalent if given a US counterpart etc, etc.

**Question**

Is it asking too much of such an implicit structure to be able to operate in this fashion. Is it bad practice to ask for such a thing?? What would be your approach to solving such a dilema. The end game would be that any equivalent should be produced as a single liner along the lines of:

```
// this should produce a value of **CupLitre**
var eqv = conversion["CupUS"][LocaleM.Metric];
```

Anyway, without further ado:

**The Example**

Whip up a console app and paste the code below into it (.net v3.5).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnitOfMeasurements;

namespace UnitOfMeasurements
{
    [Flags]
    public enum LocaleM
    {
        None = 0,   //(0000)
        Metric = 1, //(0001)
        UK = 2,     //(0010)
        US = 4,     //(0100)    
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // single structure representing UK equivalents
        // this should be extensible to any equivalent
        var conversionUK 
            = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<LocaleM, string>>
                {
                    {"PintUK", 
                        new Dictionary<LocaleM, string>
                                   {
                                       {LocaleM.US, "PintUS"},
                                       {LocaleM.Metric, "Litre"}
                                   }
                    },
                    {"FlOzUK", 
                        new Dictionary<LocaleM, string>
                                   {
                                       {LocaleM.US, "FlOzUS"},
                                       {LocaleM.Metric, "MilliLitre"}
                                   }
                    },
                    {"CupUK", 
                        new Dictionary<LocaleM, string>
                                   {
                                       {LocaleM.US, "CupUS"},
                                       {LocaleM.Metric, "CupLitre"}
                                   }
                    }
                };

        // basic printout of results
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", "Key","US","Metric"));
        foreach (var item in conversionUK)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", 
                item.Key, 
                item.Value[LocaleM.US], 
                item.Value[LocaleM.Metric]));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(string
            .Format("Here's an example of our direct 'query' - {0}",
            conversionUK["CupUK"][LocaleM.Metric]));
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Good luck - looking fwd to some simple but elegant answers.

**[edit]** - i must add that the requirement for the inputs ("PintUK", "CupMetric") etc, to be strings is a must as these values will be driving `(IVolumeUnit)Activator.CreateInstance(eqv)` methods further downstream to create concrete conversion classes of the given string names.

Comment: Are you limited to C#? If not, F# has this functionality baked in as part of the language http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewkennedy/archive/2008/08/29/units-of-measure-in-f-part-one-introducing-units.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following approach assumes that all your mappings are bidirectional and if a->b and b->c then a->c

I would introduce a concept of something like `default name` (cross-culture) for each your item to convert. For example in your code these default names could be 'Pint', 'FlOz' and 'Cup':

**UPDATE**: replaced custom MapKey class with .Net tuple to make code simplier.

```
class MapClass
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _localToDefaultNameMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    private readonly Dictionary<Tuple<string, LocaleM>, string> _defaultNameToLocalMap = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, LocaleM>, string>();

    public void AddMapping(string defaultName, LocaleM locale, string localName)
    {
        _localToDefaultNameMap.Add(localName, defaultName);
        _defaultNameToLocalMap.Add(Tuple.Create(defaultName, locale), localName);
    }

    // maps from source name to target 
    public string Map(string sourceLocalName, LocaleM targetLocale)
    {
        string defaultName = _localToDefaultNameMap[sourceLocalName];
        var mapKey = Tuple.Create(defaultName, targetLocale);
        var localName = _defaultNameToLocalMap[mapKey];
        return localName;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Creating map:
var map = new MapClass();
map.AddMapping("Pint", LocaleM.UK, "PintUK");
map.AddMapping("Pint", LocaleM.US, "PintUS");
map.AddMapping("Pint", LocaleM.Metric, "Litre");

string ukPintMappedToUS = map.Map("PintUK", LocaleM.US);
```

**UPDATE 2** MapKey equality members generated by resharper:

```
class MapKey
{
    ... 

    public bool Equals(MapKey other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return Equals(other.Locale, Locale) && Equals(other.Key, Key);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof (MapKey)) return false;
        return Equals((MapKey) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int result = 0;
        result = (result * 397) ^ Locale.GetHashCode();
        result = (result * 397) ^ (Key != null ? Key.GetHashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Snowbear - apologies, i took the liberty of editing the example to allow it to compile. this is 'almost' there, but throws an exception based on the example usage. i'll have a look at that... but in general, i really like this approach

Comment: @jim, thanks, I'm too lazy to open Studio for it, so I left those gaps. Thanks for extending it.

Comment: Snowbear, made a final change. this works perfectly now. thanks for that +1

Comment: @jim, I've removed some your changes back, I do not want to show all the best code practices so I removed all your checks back in order to make code more clear. I believe if OP will like the concept then he will be able to add stuff needed to make a production code out of it.

Comment: Haha, @Snowbear, @jim **is** the OP.

Comment: Snowbear - that made me laugh :-). also, unfortunately, tuples are .net 4 only. the solution must be for 3.5.

Comment: @jim, Oops, fail :) Ok, if you need solution for .Net 3.5 then get back with MapKey, but please instead of iterating over dictionary implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in MapKey - it will work then. :)

Comment: Snowbear - thanks, will do... (erm can you pop an example of the GetHashCode and Equals into a comment please) - doh!!

Comment: Snowbear, spot on - works 100%. have marked as answer!! nice one (oh, also added the GetHashCode() override:)